# URL of domain change in browser bar but not the content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html5-history

I want to change browser URL bar completely 
like user is visiting page

```
www.example.com
```

but URL bar says

```
www.abc.com
```

I have tried history of HTML 5 but that only change path in the domain not the whole URL.

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "../www.good.com/new-url");
window.history.pushState('/www.good.com/new-url', '', '/www.good.com/');
window.history.replaceState( {} , '/www.good.com/new-url', '/www.good.com/new-url' );
```

All three of the above stay in same domain where I hosted files.

I am prepared to use any of PHP, jQuery or JavaScript to achieve this.

Comment: I hope this doesn't work. Nothing personal but I see a big potential for scammers and phishers in this behavior. Just imagine you are visiting `haxxor.evil` and your URL bar says `legitBankWebsite.com`

Comment: If you own both domains, why not forward to the other and have the DNS both point in the same host folder?

Comment: Actually i do not own domain
i just want to change text in front-end of browsers URL address bar

Comment: No, then you can not do this, as noted in the above comment. It would be a big security hole if it was allowed.

Comment: there must be a way to breach the security :)